# Compare dates from the same table row using T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I would like to compare dates from the same table row and return the most recent date. Example below:

```
table1

id | Date1    | Date2    | Date3    | Date4    |
---|-------------------------------------------    
1  | 01/01/20 | 02/01/20 | 03/01/20 | 04/01/20 |
```

The result in this instance would be `04/01/20`

I am able to do it using the below method:

```
DECLARE @id INT; 
SET @id = 1;

select MAX(date) from

(select Date1 as date from table1 where id = @id
union
select Date2 from table1 where id = @id
union
select Date3 from table1 where id = @id
union
select Date4 from table1 where id = @id) as t
```

This to me feels like a bad solution and trying to do this on multiple records would cause a lot overhead.

Can anyone advised if there is a better way to achieve the desired outcome.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: You could add `group by` if there were multiple records

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not mention DBMS.
For mySQL, Oracle, Postgres, MariaDB, DB2 you can use below function.
`GREATEST(date1, date2, date3, ...)`
For Other DBMS, you need to use case when logic like below

```
case 
when date1> date2 and date2 > date3 then date1
when date2> date1 and date1 > date3 then date2
else date3
end as greatest_date
```

EDIT : For TSQL - you can use below logic.

```
SELECT MAX(x.CombinedDate) AS greatest
FROM   table AS u
CROSS APPLY ( VALUES ( u.date1), ( u.date2),( u.date3),( u.date4)) AS x ( CombinedDate )
```

Comment: i added another solution too. you can check that out if you have too many columns.